# Jitsi Meeting In Android Api Level 33

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, jitsi, jitsi-meet, openmeetings

I implement

```
jitsi_meet: ^4.0.0
```

in flutter.Its working fine in android and Ios both.But when i run into Android Api level 33,Application crash.Here is the error:

```
 Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
```

But i cannot use any pending intent and any Broatcast.I also implement this library:

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0
```

the error was same in android Api Level 33.Other Android device and Ios device application working fine.

Comment: I think this error is in the jitsi package.

Comment: You can get code of that package from github and then make required changes for latest API version and then use that according to your requirement.

Comment: error in notification manager class

Comment: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel shortcut=null contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0)

Comment: I believe `openmeetings` label should be removed from this question, it is not related to Apache OpenMeetings  :)